# Phoenix Elixir: is making a POST using fetch to an action and returning JSON from template view so hard?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I do have this controller and template views and I'm getting this error when POST to the create action:

Did I miss to setup some Plug in particular ?

`** (RuntimeError) expected action/2 to return a Plug.Conn, all plugs must receive a connection (conn) and return a connection`

Elixir 1.3.2
Phoenix 1.2.1
Poison 3.0

Part of the code in the controller

```
  def create(conn, %{"cart" => cart, "form" => form}) do

  ...

    if changeset_order.valid? do
      Repo.transaction fn ->
        # Save Order
        order = changeset_order 
                |> Repo.insert! 
                |> Repo.preload(:buyer)
        # Save Order Products
        Enum.map(order_products, fn order_product ->
          order_product = Repo.insert!(order_product) |> Repo.preload(:order)
          changeset = Ecto.Changeset.change(order_product) |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:order, order)
          Repo.update!(changeset)
        end)
        CheckoutService.charge_customer(total_amount, "fake-valid-nonce")
        render conn, "show.json", order: order <--- Is this failing due to is called from within a transaction ?
      end
    else
      render conn, ExRushlookApi.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset_order
    end
```

Template Views

```
defmodule ExRushlookApi.OrderView do
  use ExRushlookApi.Web, :view

  def render("index.json", %{orders: orders}) do
    %{data: render_many(orders, __MODULE__, "order.json")}
  end

  def render("show.json", %{order: order}) do
    %{data: render_one(order, __MODULE__, "order.json")}
  end

  def render("order.json", %{order: order}) do
    order |> IO.inspect
    %{id: Map.get(order, :id)}
  end

  def render("errors.json", %{errors: errors}) do
    %{errors: render_many(errors, __MODULE__, "error.json")}
  end

  def render("error.json", %{error: error}) do
    %{
      key: error.key,
      value: error.value
    }
  end

end
```

UPDATE: It works this way.

```
if changeset_order.valid? do
      {:ok, order } = Repo.transaction fn ->
        # Save Order
        order = changeset_order 
                |> Repo.insert! 
                |> Repo.preload(:buyer)
        # Save Order Products
        Enum.map(order_products, fn order_product ->
          order_product = Repo.insert!(order_product) |> Repo.preload(:order)
          changeset = Ecto.Changeset.change(order_product) |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:order, order)
          Repo.update!(changeset)
        end)

        CheckoutService.charge_customer(total_amount, "fake-valid-nonce")
        order
      end
      conn
      |> render("show.json", order: order)
    else
      conn
      |> render(ExRushlookApi.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset_order)
    end
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the `render conn, "show.json", ...` call inside your transaction block. It should be after the block. The transaction block returns the results of the transaction, not the last statement.

If you want to only render show on success, you should check the result of the transaction and handle it there.

Comment: Yes sir ! You were right. Finally did work. My fault. I updated my answer.